# divide items between two lists randomly

Tags: python

I must get items from a list by using class and inheritance and randomly append them to two lists equally,so I don`t know how to append them to lists randomly

```
import random

players = ['a', 'b', 'c','d','e', 'f']

A = []
B = []
teams = []



class Human:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name



class Player(Human):

    def __init__(self, name, team):
        self.team = team
        Human.__init__(self, name)

for i in range(6):
    p = Player(random.choice(players))
    a = p.team
    print(p.name)
    players.remove(p.name)
print(teams)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Shuffle, then halve the list.

Comment: your code will give you duplicate players.

Comment: @DanielMesejo two lists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code will give you the same players:

> ```
> for i in range(6):
>     p = Player(random.choice(players)) # you can draw duplicates here
> ```

to avoid that either use `random.sample(players, k=len(players))` over your whole names  (this returns a new, shuffled list - `players` is unmodified) or `random.shuffle(players)` it in-place. Afterwards you divide the result into two parts  and create the teams from that data:

You should probably overload the `__repr__(self)` methods of your class to make outputting neater.

```
import random

class Human:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
    def __repr__(self): return str(self)

class Player(Human):
    def __init__(self, name, team):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.team = team
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} in team {self.team}" 
    def __repr__(self): return str(self)

players = ['a', 'b', 'c','d','e', 'f']
random.shuffle(players)  # inplace shuffling

player_length = len(players) // 2 # make sure you got even player counts - else uneven teams
A = [Player(k,"A") for k in players[:player_length]]  # first 3 are Team A
B = [Player(k,"B") for k in players[player_length:]]  # rest is Team B
teams = [A,B]

print(teams)
```

Output:

```
[[d in team A, f in team A, b in team A],[a in team B, e in team B, c in team B]]
```

Doku:

- [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.sample)
- [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

Comment: Would like to see programmatic approach to determining the halfway index rather than hard coding the 3